# How to Share SharePoint 2013 sub-site with external users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, external-users

If I try to add external users other than my domain I am getting an error "you are not allowed to add external user".
I could not find any settings in central admin.
There are settings instruction for SharePoint online or office365 available on the web.
Kindly help on this.
[image]

Comment: What is your Farm type its on premises or Online

Comment: on premises. Sharepoint server 2013 enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint On-premises doesn’t have feature to share sites with external users by default.

We need to extend the web application and implement identity providers such as ADFS.

Comment: Any article or reference about ADFS ,So I can implement on my application

Comment: You can check the article: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/08/installing-and-configuring-adfs-with-sharepoint-2013.html